# "At all" in Spanish

Tags: traducción, modismos

How would one translate "at all" in the following sentences:

> 1. Let's hope she was cute, that is if at all she existed.
> 2. Did you know her at all?
> 3. No, not at all!

For the last one, **claro** (as in, **¡claro que no!**) comes to mind but I'd wait for someone to give a better, more natural translation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first two are hard to translate literally, I'll try my best and also give you wordings that sound better to me:

1. Let's hope she was cute, that is if at all she existed.

   - Literal:

     - Esperemos que fuese guapa, eso si siquiera existió.
   - Reworded:

     - [...] eso si existió realmente/de verdad. --- ([...] that's if she really existed).
2. Did you know her at all?

   - I can't think of any literal translation to this one
   - Reworded:

     - ¿En serio la conocías? --- (Did you really know her?)
     - ¿Seguro que la conocías? --- (Are you sure you knew her?)
     - No la conocías *en absoluto*/*para nada*, ¿no/verdad? --- (You didn't know her at all, right?)
3. No, not at all!

   - Literal:

     - ¡No, en absoluto!
     - ¡No, para nada! (slightly informal)
     - ¡No, qué va! (informal)
     - ¡No, [pero] qué dices! (annoyed, *pero* is optional)

Comment: `...si acaso existió`, eliminates the cacophony of `si siquiera`.

Answer (score 2):

I hear it only to emphasize something negative (like in 3.). In this case you can say

> para nada [No, not at all = No, para nada]
>
> en absoluto
>
> de ninguna forma
>
> en lo más mínimo

In the other case I suppose you can say

> por completo
>
> totalmente